# Куда записывается значение?

Tags: javascript

```
function Parent(args){
    this.prop = args;
}

function Child(args){
    Parent.call(this, args);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child('test');
/**
 * 1) Куда сохраняется строка 'test'
 *    при такой постановке?
 */

function Parent(args){
    this.prop = args;
}

function Child(args){
    Parent.call(this);

    this.prop = args;
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child('test');

/**
 * 2) Куда сохраняется строка 'test'
 *    при такой постановке?
 */

function Test(args){
    this.prop = args; // присваивая значение здесь
}

Test.prototype = {
    prop: undefined; // оно запишется сюда? Это вопрос 3.
}

var test = new Test('test');
```

Comment: Во всех случаях запишется в соответствующий инстанс. В #3 вы просто задали значение по умолчанию через прототип: http://jsbin.com/hamidahokihi/1/edit

Comment: Если разбирать третий вопрос, то this.prop в конструкторе ссылается на одноименное свойство в прототипе?

Comment: Да, но только до той поры, пока вы его не переопределили.

Comment: А где я его переопределил?

Comment: `this.prop = prop;`

Comment: То есть, у меня теперь в памяти два свойства? Один со значением args, а другой undefined?

Comment: Не совсем так, просто изначально, пока вы не определили это свойство, оно ссылалось на значение в прототипе. Если очень просто, у вас есть свойство в прототипе и свойство в инстансе, если вы его определили, если вы его удалите, то оно опять будет ссылаться на свойство в прототипе.